# findnext() function call fails on second call. Program crashes

Tags: c, msvcrt

The `_findnext()` function is not working when called for the second time. Here is the code.

```
int main() {
    struct _finddata_t ffblk;
    intptr_t done;

    chdir("tmp");
    printf("Directory changed to dir successfully\n");

    done=_findfirst("*.txt",&ffblk);
    printf("Call to findfirst successful\n");
    printf("%s\n",ffblk.name);
    do{
        done=_findnext(done,&ffblk);
        printf("%s\n",ffblk.name);
    } while(!done);
    printf("Exited the main loop\n");
    getch();
}
```

The program crashes once it gets and prints the name of first two files in the folder `tmp`.
The first file name printed is from the `findfirst()` function. The next file name is printed by `findnext()`. I have checked via debugging.

Now when `findnext()` is called the second time in the loop, the program crashes. I am using gcc and tried most of the things with return value too, but no success. Any ideas ?

Comment: What is `_findfirst`, `_findnext`, `_find*`? I don't recall this being in the C standard.

Comment: Did you use a debugger and check in which line it crashes?

Comment: Google tells me `_find*` is part of Microsoft's Visual C++. I'd suggest an edit with appropriate tags.

Comment: Check the docs, `_findfirst` apparently returns an `intptr_t`, `_findnext` an `int`

Comment: findfirst is in C standard library, is used to find a file with given specifications but works with 16 bit compiler only. I found on google that in order to use this stuff on 32 bit compiler, I need to go with _findfirst and similar functions.

Comment: @Thomas : I don't use a debugger, but I used a lot of printf statements and other ways to make sure that this line:- "done=_findnext(done,&ffblk);"
when called second time, is causing crash. Thats a confirm. No matter how many text files are there in tmp folder.

Comment: @vish213 you must have misread that I guess - why should some **standard** call only work with a (stoneage) 16 bits compiler???

Comment: @fvu : I tried that way too, didn't worked for me. But OK I'll try again because earlier I had made "done" variable int, so now I'll try with a new variable. Don't think It'll make a difference though.

Comment: @vish213 could you also tell us what version of the compiler you're using here?

Comment: @fvu : maybe I failed to explain properly here.
Actually those functions used some struct ffblk, which works with 16 bit compiler only. I read somewhere(maybe on stackoverflow itself) that i need to go with struct _finddata_t.

Comment: @vish213 - No. The C standard does not prescribe special functions for 16 bit compilers. There is no mention of `findfirst` of `_findfirst` **anywhere in the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)**.

Comment: @vish213 - Before you try anything else, consider reading [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235422/is-there-a-standard-way-to-do-findfirst-findnext-with-gcc-on-linux-using-stl)

Comment: @fvu: I am not sure how to check that. But its release date is 26 April(as mentioned on file name). Should I check that via some googling on how to check version of gcc?

Comment: @vish213, which operating system are you using? Which `#include` do you use in order to be able to use this `_find*` stuff? GCC version can usually be had by executing `gcc --version` (atleast this is how my copy of GCC on a GNU/Linux distro works. Don't know about Windows.)

Comment: @vish213 if you're using GCC there's no reason not to stick to the C library standard functions `opendir - readdir - closedir`.  I was under the impression you were using Visual C++.

Comment: @ArjunShankar: Everything is working good, except for the second call to _findnext(). I am not having any problems like some library function not found while compiling. Shall I still be digging deeper into the link you provided? No offences but only because TO ME it seems like you are trying to tell there might be some problems with function like _findfirst(),_findnext() not available.

Comment: @ArjunShankar : I'm on Windows 7 --GCC version 4.6.2(thnx). And these functions are from io.h

Comment: @vish213 - I'm not offended :) I'm just trying to find out *which* library you're using. The functions are (clearly) not in the C standard. Unless people know which library you're using, all the guesswork/comments are moot. You probably observed that somebody has already edited your question and added the "Microsoft Visual C Runtime" tag to it. You say you're using GCC. I don't know enough about Windows development to even say if GCC can compile against MSVCRT.

Comment: @fvu : May be you just told the best way, but shouldn't I still know whats going wrong? There is something I could not digest because the function is not working as per its library definition-findnext() is supposed to keep providing files with given criteria untill there are no more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you cannot assign the value of `_findnext` to your handle, you need two variables:

```
intptr_t handle = 0;
int done = 0;

handle = _findfirst("*.txt",&ffblk);
while(handle && done != -1)
{
    printf("%s\n",ffblk.name);
    done = _findnext(handle,&ffblk);
}
```

Comment: `_findfirst()` returns **-1** on failure, not 0.

Comment: Wait it worked!!
Thanks. I didn't correct parameters of _findnext. Thanku v much.